# Dataframe sort_values result is wrong?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

there is a dataframe, when it is be sorted by col name 2,4, it can work fine, but sorted by col name 1, it's got wrong result.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.array(labels).reshape([-1,1]),picked_box_probs[:,:4]]))
Out[59]: 
   0           1           2           3          4
0  皖   5.7159505   11.721471    31.53594  59.627377
1  2    174.8078  10.9442625   201.33795  62.615562
2  6    147.1714  10.0783825    173.1844   61.20856
3  8    93.03298   11.160529  117.985115  60.283916
4  A   33.483356  11.9336815   58.625034  59.587143
5  N   65.282814   11.349585    90.84942   59.98239
6  X  120.351524   11.449275   145.36586  61.187523

pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([np.array(labels).reshape([-1,1]),picked_box_probs[:,:4]])).sort_values(1)
Out[60]: 
   0           1           2           3          4
6  X  120.351524   11.449275   145.36586  61.187523
2  6    147.1714  10.0783825    173.1844   61.20856
1  2    174.8078  10.9442625   201.33795  62.615562
4  A   33.483356  11.9336815   58.625034  59.587143
0  皖   5.7159505   11.721471    31.53594  59.627377
5  N   65.282814   11.349585    90.84942   59.98239
3  8    93.03298   11.160529  117.985115  60.283916
```

try all the col names .

Comment: Please provide a Reproducible Example. See how to create one here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
In your case, what is `labels`?

Check this article to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data is being ordered alphabetically on column `1`, instead of numerically.
Make sure the data has the correct type. You can use `pd.Series.astype` to cast the column to the data type you want.